# Combine browserify and WebWorker

Tags: javascript, module, browserify, web-worker

I'm using browserify to pack my app and use js files as modules.

Now I want to use a webworker to upload a very big file on the background.

The problem I have is that to create this worker the instruction

```
new Worker('./worker.js')
```

must receive the name of a js file. So that this file cannot be a module. I think that this makes my app much more complicated, because now I have to combine two ways of using js files.

On the other hand, I'm interested in accessing a browserify module from this worker too.

So the question is, Which is the best way of using browserify and web workers together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [webworkify](https://github.com/substack/webworkify) to handle this

Comment: but what if webworkify uses blobs to expose the workers and the Content Security Policy restricts with default-src: 'self'. I don't want to add child-src: 'blob' or unsafe-eval to the CSP. Is there still a way to add web workers to a browserify environment

Comment: @MattWilde that sounds like a question outside the scope of whats being asked. Ask about that in a separate question.